# Trouble creating ext4 filesystem when trying to mount EBS volume on AWS instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-ebs, ext4

I'm trying to mount an EBS volume on my AWS instance. Following [Amazon's instructions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-using-volumes.html), I get the following error when running `sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/xvdf`:

```
Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): mkfs.ext4: symbol lookup error: mkfs.ext4: undefined symbol: ext2fs_add_journal_inode2
```

I have tried using ext3 and ext2 and continue to get the "undefined symbol" error.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like `mkfs.ext4` and the libraries it depend on are of incompatible versions. Is there more than one `mkfs.ext4` executable on the host? Which package manager was it installed through?

Comment: Doesn't look like there are duplicate mkfs.ext4 executables. There are duplicates of libcom_err, however which is one of the dependencies. Would that be the cause of the problem? Yum is the package manager.

Comment: The error message sounds like it is trying to find `ext2fs_add_journal_inode2` in a library. The only library I could imagine that symbol being found in is `libext2fs`. Are `mkfs.ext4` and `libext2fs` provided by the same package? Have you tried to run an `rpm` command to verify that the package is installed correctly?